# Text Area in material-ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Could someone help me making a TextField personalization into a TextArea, using material-ui library? I am not finding any parameter that should personalize it into a TextArea: https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/v1-beta/src/TextField/TextField.d.ts

This is the TextArea:https://material.io/guidelines/components/text-fields.html#text-fields-field-types (CMD/Ctrl + F 'Text area').

> Text areas are taller than text fields and wrap overflow text onto a
>   new line. They scroll vertically when the cursor reaches the bottom of
>   the field.

Answer (score 187):

To make `TextField` work like a `textarea` you can use `multiline` prop. You can read more about `TextFied` and its `props` [here](https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/nts/text-field).

**Example**

```
<TextField
  placeholder="MultiLine with rows: 2 and rowsMax: 4"
  multiline
  rows={2}
  maxRows={4}
/>
```

You can set `maxRows={Infinity}` if you want to scale your multiline input box with your content (regardless of the content length).

Comment: @BishopZ it is hard to say what is the problem without a [mcve].

Comment: Tip: You can set `rowsMax={Infinity}` if you want to scale your multiline input box with your content (regardless of the content length).

Comment: But the inner text of the `TextField` is basically getting smaller in size. Do we have to override it with the custom css ?

Comment: actually the properties are named minRows and maxRows (not rowsMax and rowsMin).  By default without specifying these properties it will grow to fit the text.

Comment: [New link to the docs](https://mui.com/api/text-field/) It should be the accepted answer.

Comment: You cannot use the *minRows* or *maxRows* props when the input *rows* is set.

Answer (score 8):

We can use outlined multiline `<TextField>` for text area
and it could be implemented by creating a theme to apply globally anywhere inside `<App/>`

#### theme.js

```
import { createMuiTheme} from '@material-ui/core/styles';
const theme = createMuiTheme({
 overrides: {
    MuiOutlinedInput: {
        multiline: {
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            fontSize: '20px',
            color: 'purple',
            width: '50vw'
        }
    }
}
  
});
export default theme;
```

#### app.js

```
...
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Theme from './relevant-path-where-the-above-theme.js-file-is-saved/Theme';
...
...
render() {
    
    return (
      <ThemeProvider theme={Theme}>
        <div className="App"> 
            <Routes/>
        </div>
      </ThemeProvider>
        
    );
  }
```

#### SomeComponent.js

```
...
<TextField
  id="outlined-multiline-static"
  label="Multiline"
  multiline
  rows={10}
  variant="outlined"
/>
...
```

Now the style for outlined multiline `<TextField>` will be applied globally
[image]

Answer (score 5):

You should use `TextareaAutosize` API available in material UI.

```
import TextareaAutosize from '@material-ui/core/TextareaAutosize';
```

or

```
import { TextareaAutosize } from '@material-ui/core';
```

The following example has all the attributes of TextareaAutosize:
https://material-ui.com/components/textarea-autosize/

You can learn more about the difference between the two imports by reading [this guide](https://v4.mui.com/guides/minimizing-bundle-size/).

Comment: but does not look like a material at all

Comment: do you have any idea how to use this component with a `InputBase` in order to have same style and theme

Comment: Instead of TextareaAutosize, which looks like garbage, set these attributes on a TextField: `multiline minRows={3} maxRows={20}, eg: <TextField fullWidth multiline minRows={3} maxRows={20} />. multiline = textarea, maxRows = autosize up to this many rows, optional minRows = minimum rows to use.

Answer (score 1):

If you want something simple instead of the whole material-ui component, just use this code:

```
textarea.style.height = textarea.scrollHeight+'px'
```

Where `scrollHeight` is inner height of textarea and `style.height` is outer (if outer < inner, scrollbar shows)